# what does server.applyMiddleware({ app }); in graphql integration with apollo-server means

Tags: express, graphql, apollo, middleware, apollo-server

here,

**http://https:%20www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/middleware/#apollo-server-express**

as a logic to integrate express with apollo-server they used

```js
      import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } from 'apollo-server-core';
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';

async function startApolloServer(typeDefs, resolvers) {
  const app = express();
  const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    plugins: [ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer })],
  });
  await server.start();
  server.applyMiddleware({ app });
  await new Promise(resolve => httpServer.listen({ port: 4000 }, resolve));
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`);
}
```

what does **server.applyMiddleware({ app });** means, i know that "app" is an express app instance, but why passing it as middleware to apollo-server.. its not a middleware itself!!!

i understand passing special real middleware(called rest) to server like this **app.use(server.getMiddleware(rest))**
i need to understand passing the app inside apply middlware

Answer (score 0):

The docs says:

> You can call `server.getMiddleware` instead of `server.applyMiddleware` if you want to do something with the middleware function besides apply it directly to your app. (`server.applyMiddleware({ app, ...rest })` is shorthand for `app.use(server.getMiddleware(rest))`.)

The [source code](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/a0ccf23f50ae51e00a4f2fb260ce44d4b191eb5f/packages/apollo-server-express/src/ApolloServer.ts#L69) of `applyMiddleware` for `apollo-server-express` package:

```js
public applyMiddleware({ app, ...rest }: ServerRegistration) {
    // getMiddleware calls this too, but we want the right method name in the error
    this.assertStarted('applyMiddleware');

    app.use(this.getMiddleware(rest));
}
```